# UML Activity Diagram for Calculating itinerary

Tags: uml, diagram

I recently created a UML Activity diagram for a part of my app that calculates length and time for a selected road

So the user will indicate his destination and the app will send his current location with destination to Directions API that will calculate the length and time of course this operation will be done if there is an internet connection.

Comment: "ideas to improve it" is off-topic as question. Please ask a concrete question.

Comment: I edit it thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the diagram is ok. However, there is one issue with it. The `Get current location` action has no start. I assume that it is triggered by `Application` sort of a periodic task. So you should place an `EntryPoint` inside `Application`.

Another point: I'd introduce a separate lane for the `Display`. That will help you also during class design towards the MVC paradigm. Your display actions are now mixed in the `Application` and `User` lanes.

Comment: Thank you so much for your great answer. For your second point i didn't understand it well .the result will be displayed in the app while the user will consult it

Comment: @Jim L you mean that get corrent location can be without start??

Comment: @JimL. Though correct, I think that an EntryPoint is much more clear to the reader.

Comment: The second point about the additional lane for the display is meant to bundle visual interaction (GUI). So the Display Error and Show Route would be placed in a Display lane.

Comment: Yes, it can be without start. People don't understand the token semantics of activity diagrams. Please look for my previous answers here, where I refer to Conrad Bock's excellent series of articles. He has the clearest, most correct explanation anywhere.

Comment: @ThomasKilian ok  i get it now thank you so much for your time